# How to read the value to text box from app config

Tags: c#, vb.net, app-config, vb.net-2010

I have added key values in appconfig of vb.net

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="Key0" value="0" />
<add key="Key1" value="1" />
<add key="Key2" value="2" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I would like to loop through all the keyvalues in app config and read the value to textbox1,textbox2 and textbox3.

I have done some work on it but failed to achieve it below is what i tried.

```
If form1.combobox1.selecteditem = 0 then
Dim appsettings = configurationmanager.appsettings
dim result as string
for each result in appsetting
if result = appsettings("Key1") then
textbox1.text = result
else
if result = appsettings("key2") then
textbox2.text = result
end if
next
```

The above throwed error in if condition, could you please help me to get the solution to read the values to textbox from Appconfig file in VB.net platform.

Comment: What error it is throwing?

Comment: Your keys are sequentially numbered.  A `For` loop is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by `If form1.combobox1.selecteditem = 0 then`
If there is a 0 in the box then `If ComboBox1.SelectedText = "0" Then` should work. The items in a combobox are objects.
If you mean there are no selected items then `If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1`
You were missing an End If so I added it where I thought it might belong

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedText = "0" Then
            Dim appsettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
            Dim result As String
            For Each result In appsettings
                If result = appsettings("Key1") Then
                    TextBox1.Text = result
                ElseIf result = appsettings("key2") Then
                    TextBox2.Text = result
                End If
            Next
End If
```

If you can download Visual Studio Community 2017 (it's free) and set Option Strict on, it will be a big help to you coding.
Code is not tested against app.config.

Comment: I have not tried this however i will come back in the same thread after trying your solution thank you for the reply.